# Exporting Excel file containing dates to data Grid view

Tags: c#, excel, datagridview

I want to export excel file having dates and day and some text to an data grid view
and the data grid view must show same content in excel

I am trying following code to export it to excel

```
        //for (row = 9; row < 40; row++)
        //{
        //    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
        //    for (column = 1; column <= 7; column++)
        //    {
        //        dr[column - 1] = (range.Cells[row, column] as Excel.Range).Value2;
        //    }
        //    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        //    dt.AcceptChanges();
        //}

        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

but my grid view is not showing content as same in excel.

Comment: Do you have formula or type formatting for cells in the excel? If so, those won't show up in your grid.
If the content is not sensitive info you can put that as part of your query to help others to understand the problem.

Comment: You'll need to share the secret about what exactly the difference between your Excel content and your data grid is.

Comment: i have date and time in my excel row but the date and times are appearing proprly in the grid view..

Comment: @SandeepGB yea i have type formatig for the time it is in [h]:mm format ....